# Blocking external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm building a UserScript and I try to block an external JS script (ckeditor.js) loaded from the HTML code.

It should be easy with "**beforescriptexecute**" but there is a catch: The site use [RocketLoader](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-) which is a sort of cache for js scripts.

Let me show you the HTML code and the custom Script tag:

```
<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Since the tag is "custom" "**beforescriptexecute**" event is not able to stop ckeditor.js from running.

Do you know how I can block this script only (from my userscript) **?**

Comment: So this is an Addon you want to disable, using JavaScript?

Comment: No I can disable the script using addon but I want to do it from a Userscript/Greasemonkey Script.

Comment: define a non-configurable global in the way of whatever the script uses/needs; maybe `Object.defineProperty(window, "CKEditor",{value: {}})`... this will prevent the script from working no matter how it's loaded

Comment: @dandavis Could you give me an example ? I've tried but it don't seem to work. Here's the source page: http://pagebin.com/

Comment: the global is `CKEDITOR`; i guessed wrong.

Comment: @dandavis Just tried it did not stop the the file from running !

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(window, "CKEDITOR",{value: {}})` works; tested just now, leaving a textarea. make sure to run `localStorage.clear()` to remove any memorized "rocket" modules...

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
document.querySelector("script[data-rocketsrc='ckeditor/ckeditor.js']").remove()
```

Comment: Sadly it did not work, here's the web page in question: http://pagebin.com/

Comment: I upvoted this because it's a good idea, but shame on you man, it really doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to go around this. I will mention them:

- Destroy ckeditor after page loads
- Enable <kbd>Toggle sourcecode</kbd> button for ckeditor (yes, it is possible)
- Tamper with cloudflare's cache

I already did those first two, so I decided to try the third option. If you print `localStorage contents in console, you can see how this cache works:

[image: image description]

For every script, there's an entry. The JSON structure looks like this:

```
{
    "url": "http://pagebin.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js",
    "contents": "/*script code here*/",
    "version": "0.1.33",
    "ctime": 1471875453444,
    "stime": 1471875453444,
    "ttl": 604800000,
    "meta": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "200"
    ]
}
```

All you need is to set the contents to empty string:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Disable cloudflare cached script
// @namespace   util
// @description Prevents script from being used from cache. It can still be loaded normally.
// @include     http://pagebin.com/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// @author       http://stackoverflow.com/a/39082174/607407
// ==/UserScript==
var ckeditorURL = "CLOUDFLARE::http://pagebin.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js";


var json = JSON.parse(localStorage[ckeditorURL]);
json.contents = "// nothing here, move along";
localStorage[ckeditorURL] = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Result:

[image: image description]